# ntpdate: no server suitable for synchronization found [NO FIREWALL]

Tags: linux, ntp

I have a private NTP server which again get its time from upstream NTPs and provide ntp service for the LAN.

Time of server:
Mon Dec 10 12:05:37 CET 2018

Time of client:
Mon Dec 10 12:05:37 CET 2018

Running with:

```
 ntpdate -dv 10.0.0.1
10 Dec 12:07:27 ntpdate[27873]: ntpdate 4.2.8p11@1.3728-o (1)
Looking for host 10.0.0.1 and service ntp
host found : 10.0.0.1
transmit(10.0.0.1)
receive(10.0.0.1)
transmit(10.0.0.1)
receive(10.0.0.1)
transmit(10.0.0.1)
receive(10.0.0.1)
transmit(10.0.0.1)
receive(10.0.0.1)
server 10.0.0.1, port 123
stratum 3, precision -23, leap 00, trust 000
refid [10.0.0.1], delay 0.05977, dispersion 0.00775
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    dfb8c622.a68c0570  Mon, Dec 10 2018 12:01:54.650
originate timestamp: dfb8c775.e10326b2  Mon, Dec 10 2018 12:07:33.878
transmit timestamp:  dfb8c775.d8a2c056  Mon, Dec 10 2018 12:07:33.846
filter delay:  0.06314  0.09708  0.05977  0.08392
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: -0.00401 0.007043 -0.00917 0.003483
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.05977, dispersion 0.00775
offset -0.009173

10 Dec 12:07:33 ntpdate[27873]: adjust time server 10.0.0.1 offset -0.009173 sec
```

Seems to be fine but then running it in real mode I keep getting:

no server suitable for synchronization found

I put it into the ntp.conf and start the daemon it will hang with:

```
10.0.0.1  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

forever. There is no firewall. Port also verified with nmap.

Why?!?

Comment: What did you put into ntp.conf?

Comment: server 10.0.0.1

Comment: `ntpdate` sends packets from a high-numbered port; `ntpd` sends packets from port 123; it's highly likely that your egress traffic is restricted by a firewall, possibly in your ISP's network rather than yours.  (Some ISPs do this to prevent poorly-configured NTP servers from being used in DDoS amplification attacks.)